# Autodesk - Model Properties API - Out of Memory

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

Autodesk Construction Cloud - [Model Properties API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/model-properties/).

I'm trying to index and query uploaded Navisworks model. The model size is 241Mb.

When trying to [index](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-jobs-batch-status-post/) the properties the indexing fails as follows:

```
"indexes": [
    {
        ...
        "type": "INDEX",
        "state": "FAILED",
        ...
        "errors": [
            {
                "type": "RuntimeError",
                "title": "OutOfMemoryException",
                "detail": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Does the indexing has a limit on Autodesk Backend?
What could be done in such case?

Comment: AFAIK there are no specific limits but of course, if a model is sufficiently large or complex, it will always make the worker run out of memory.

Comment: If you could share the URN of the seed file (either here or via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`), the engineering team would be happy to check the logs to get more details for us.

Comment: The Version ID: urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:vf.e2OZJREyRNa7WOmTLLlSuA?version=1
The URN (relationships.derevatives.data.id): dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwZW1lYTpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmUyT1pKUkV5Uk5hN1dPbVRMTGxTdUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x.

Comment: Thank you, I've provided your info to the engineering team, and will report here when I get their feedback.